# Как использовать 1 скрипт в разных html файлах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Все перепробовал что бы перенести переменную из скрипта одного html в другой.

Html#1

```
<input type="text" class="i-1">
<input type="submit" class="btn">
```

script

```
const block = document.querySelector('.i-1');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', raVe);
}
function raVe() {
    var bValue = block.value;
    return bValue;
}
let x = `${raVe()}`;
```

Возможно ли реализовать например что бы результат переменной выводился уже на другую страницу html???

Comment: Уточните. Две разные страницы? Две одинаковые, но открытые в разных местах? Вторая страница уже открыта в этот момент или нужно открыть с этими данными?

Comment: Можно попробовать записать значение в localStorage и им пользоваться

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы передать переменную на другую страницу, скажем, **2.html**, требуется перенаправление на эту страницу, в конце которого поставить знак вопроса, и после него имя этой переменной. Т. е., 9-ю строку **return bValue;** поменять на это: **location.href = "2.html?" + encodeURIComponent(bValue);** А это: **let x = `${raVe()}`;** - убрать. На второй странице **2.html** написать такой принимающий JS-код:

```js
let received = decodeURIComponent(location.search.substring(1));
alert("получено с другой страницы: " + received);
```

Взято от сюда: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get) Можно так же всё, что нужно сделать внутри тега кнопки:

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="location.href = '2.html?' + encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('.i-1').value)" />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)